# ValueError: Number of labels=25 does not match number of samples=56

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, decision-tree, knn

I am getting this in

> C:/Users/HP/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last): 
>   File "C:/Users/HP/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 25,
>   in  dtree.fit(x_train,y_train) 
>  
>   File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py",
>   line 801, in fit X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted) 
>   File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py",
>   line 236, in fit "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples)) 
>   ValueError: Number of labels=45 does not match number of samples=36

I am using DecisionTree model but I am getting error. Help will be appreciated.

```
#importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#reading the dataset
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\csv\kyphosis.csv')
print(df)
print(df.head())

#visualising the dataset
print(sns.pairplot(df,hue='Kyphosis',palette='Set1'))
plt.show()

#training and testing
from sklearn.modelselection import traintestsplit 
c=df.drop('Kyphosis',axis=1) d=df['Kyphosis'] 
xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest=traintestsplit(c,d,testsize=0.30)

#Decision_Tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree.fit(xtrain,ytrain)

#Predictions
predictions=dtree.predict(xtest) from sklearn.metrics import 
classificationreport,confusionmatrix 
print(classificationreport(ytest,predictions)) 
print(confusionmatrix(y_test,predictions))
```

Expected result should be my `classification_report` and `confusion_matrix`

Comment: which line is throwing the error? could you include the traceback?

Comment: C:/Users/HP/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 25, in <module>
    dtree.fit(x_train,y_train)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 801, in fit
    X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 236, in fit
    "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))
ValueError: Number of labels=45 does not match number of samples=36

Comment: You're using `train_test_split` wrong. The results should be stored in the variables as follows: `xtrain,xtest,ytrain, ytest=train_test_split(c,d,testsize=0.30)`. Edit your post with the shapes of `xtrain` and `ytrain` if this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the error is thrown by the function `dtree.fit(xtrain, ytrain)`, because `xtrain` and `ytrain` have unequal length.

Checking the part of code that generates it:

```
xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest=traintestsplit(c,d,testsize=0.30)
```

and comparing to the example in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

> ```
> import numpy as np
> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
> [...]
> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
> ```

you can see two things:

1 `traintestsplit` should be `train_test_split`

2 by changing the order of variables left of the `=`, you assign different data to these variables.

so, your code should be:

```
 xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(c,d,testsize=0.30)
```